# Graphics and animation in android

Tags: android, animation, graphics, opengl-es, android-ndk

i m doing project in android
my topic is Wireless Gaming (Via Bluetooth)

i developed some basic games like TicTacToy and SOS
but now i want some graphics and animation in games

i have google for it
but didnt find good tutorial or else
i havent idea about this
i just heard that we can use OpenGL for this
can anyone help for for the tutorial for opengl in andorid
there is any other way for devloping a game in android
what is best and easy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Tutorials on OpenGL for Android [Here](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/)

Answer (score 2):

See [NeHe tutorial](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/) for android, sources you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/nehe-android/)